# How can you plot a function that contains a sum that depends on the explicit variable of the function?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the following function in Mathematica
$$f(\beta)=\frac{a^2}{2}\sum_{N} \left[N^2 \frac{e^\frac{-\beta a^2 N^2}{2}}{\sum_N e^{-\frac{\beta a^2 N^2}{2}}} \right] $$
My Mathematica code for this is as follows:

```
a = 1.602*10^-19

f[β_] := Sum[
         j^2*Exp[-(β*a^2*j^2/2)]/Sum[Exp[-a^2*β*i^2/2], {i, 0, 10}],
         {j, 0, 10}]

Plot[f[β], {β, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> All]
```

However, plotting this gives an absolutely straight line, which I am sure should not be the case. How can I get the plot to account for the exponential factor?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you question and for providing the code you tried. That's not always the case with a new poster!

Your value of a is so small that all of your exponentials are essentially 1 and the double sum evaluates to 35.

Note also that your code for the function f does not contain the a^/2 term in the definition you originally describe.